# solve for elimination constant K

Tags: excel

Can someone show me how to isolate K in the following equation?  (I want to use excel to find K, and I will know a,b,c,d,and f, so I need K isolated):

a = (b/c * exp(-K*d)+a)*exp(-Kf)

Comment: This question would be better asked on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is arithmetic, not an Excel question. (When you isolate K, putting this in Excel is relatively simple).